# Make the app compatible with 32bit iOS devices, now only works for with 64bit devices

Tags: ios, iphone, architecture, 32-bit, iphone-4

I just released a new version of my app and noticed that it says it's only compatible with iPhone 5s and later on the App Store, all of which run on 64bit processor. so my users with iPhone 5, 4s, and 4 won't be able to update the app.

I don't know if I changed anything unintentionally that has caused this, but I do want the users with 32bit architecture to be able to download the app.

as the picture below shows in my architectures I have armv7 and armv7s to support iPhone 4 and 5, so I don't know how to fix this issue.

[image]

on my info.plist I have,

[image]
I greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tested in an iPhone 5/4?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone 4/5. so no I didn't test it on them before releasing. but it runs on 4s simulator

Comment: You have in your info.plis UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities ?

Comment: I added a picture of it

Comment: I found 2 links, but, at a first look I did not see anything that can cause your error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343242/how-to-convert-xcode-32-bit-app-into-64-bit-xcode-app

Comment: my problem is actually the opposite of these questions. They want to be able to supper 64bit, but I'm wondering why my program doesn't support 32bit.

Comment: Exactly, you have not the "right" setting for 64 only mode, thats why is confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found two links for your requirements

[64 bit details](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a)

> And check your minimum deployment target ,if its sets to 7.0 then the
>   xcode will do manage 64bit or 32bit .

also check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: The minimum deployment of my previous version was ios 8, and it still ran on 32bit devices. something else must be causing this.

Comment: still you are facing problem ? @Mona

Comment: you can try with deployment target 7.1 .

Answer (score 0):

Build Active Architecture Only should be NO then you support 32 bit architecture as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you `archive` your project please choose the `Generic iOS Device`, not any real devices.