# How to convert app from 32 bit to 64 bit in Xcode 7.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-architecture

When I install app over OTA, it says "my app May Slow Down your iPad - The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility".
I researched and I got that my application is running with Architectures 32 bit $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT), it need to convert to 64 bit.

I changed Architectures to Standard architectures (armv7, arm64). Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s. Build Active Architecture to NO:

[image]

Then My app can work in simulator but When I Archive Xcode say that "Build Fail"

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the failure reason? How do you expect people to help when you don't post the relevant portion of the build log?

Comment: Have you referred this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28343925/6742121?

Comment: Please post the complete error text from Xcode, otherwise it's not clear for what reason it failed.

Comment: See [ask] and post a [mcve] (or at least the error messages).

Comment: @KAR, I did with the guide you sent the link but sill got error

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but Xcode does not show the log. I ran in xcode 7.3.1 and 8 but still same error. please the screen shot in my answers

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing any error message, but you have obviously not updated your app in ages (since 32-bit only hasn't been allowed for years), so I suspect that you may be using some 32-bit only libraries that you need to update.