# Integer literal '115000159351' overflows when stored into 'Int' but works fine in one project but not another - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a library from zendesk for iOS and I use a number they give me to sort help desk items by category. This is how I tell it what category I want:

```
        hcConfig.groupIds = [115000159351]
```

However, XCODE is throwing the error of

```
Integer literal '115000159351' overflows when stored into 'Int'
```

Ok, I understand. Probably because the number is more than 32 bits. But I have another app I made that I have an equally long number with, and that one builds just fine with no errors. Same exact code, except slightly different number.

```
    hcConfig.groupIds = [115000158052]
```

Why will one project build but the other will not?

For reference here is their instructions:
https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios_support_sdk/help_center#filter-articles-by-category

Comment: Probably one is compiled as a 32 bit app and the other as a 64 bit app.

Comment: I checked and both apps are arm64 in the build settings :(

Comment: actually I found the issue. The one app that was working with no errors I was only running as debug on simulator, so it was only building the 64 bit version.

The app that is not working I was building release (archive) version so it was trying to build BOTH 64 bit and 32 bit. 

I need to support both 64 bit and 32 bit devices.

So how can I use the number 115000159351 in a NSnumber like above and still get a successful build for both 32 bit and 64 bit?

Comment: What about `hcConfig.groupIds = [115000159351 as Int64]` ?

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '[Int64]' to type '[NSNumber]'

Answer (score 3):

The Swift `Int` is a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, depending on the platform.
To create a `NSNumber` (array) from a 64-bit literal on all platforms, use

```
let groupIds = [NSNumber(value: 115000159351 as Int64)]
```

or

```
let groupIds = [115000159351 as Int64 as NSNumber]
```

Comment: that seems like it should work but I get Cannot assign value of type '[[NSNumber]]' to type '[NSNumber]'

Comment: @JohnRogersColumbiaEDU: Are you wrapping the `groupdIds` into another array?. I would expect that `hcConfig.groupIds = groupIds` or `hcConfig.groupIds = [115000159351 as Int64 as NSNumber]` compiles.

Answer (score 2):

When both the integers converted to binary they needed equal bits around ~37

```
1101011000110100010110010110001110111 = 115000159351
1101011000110100010110010011101100100 = 115000158052
```

So, it seems that the one which is working is compiled as 64 bit app, where in the one failing is being compiled as 32 bit app. 
Please verify once.

Please refer [How to convert xcode 32 bit app into 64 bit xcode app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343242/how-to-convert-xcode-32-bit-app-into-64-bit-xcode-app) to convert your app from 32 bit to 64 bit

For using large numbers in NSNumber use following method :

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:115000159351];
```

Further, following code works fine for me on 32 bit also :

```
var groupIds = [NSNumber]();
groupIds = [115000158052, 115000158053, 115000158054]
groupIds = [115000158052 as NSNumber, 115000158053  as NSNumber, 115000158054 as NSNumber]
groupIds = [115000158052 as Int64 as NSNumber, 115000158053  as Int64 as NSNumber, 115000158054 as Int64 as NSNumber]
```

I think groupIds are not NSNumber but Int.

Comment: I checked and both apps are arm64 in the build settings :(

Comment: actually I found the issue. The one app that was working with no errors I was only running as debug on simulator, so it was only building the 64 bit version.

The app that is not working I was building release (archive) version so it was trying to build BOTH 64 bit and 32 bit. 

I need to support both 64 bit and 32 bit devices.

So how can I use the number 115000159351 in a NSnumber like above and still get a successful build for both 32 bit and 64 bit?

Comment: you can use [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:115000159351];, updated the answer. Please check this way once.